# (Rcpp, armadillo) convert arma::vec to arma::mat

Tags: r, type-conversion, rcpp

I have a matrix X, which is vectorized by `arma::vectorise` function. After some computation on the converted vector x, I want to reshape it into `arma::mat`. I tried to use `.reshape` function in Armadillo, but it gives me this error.

**Rcpp code**

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat vec2mat(arma::vec x, int nrow, int ncol){
  return x.reshape(nrow, ncol);
}
```

**Error message**

```
no viable conversion from returned value of type 'void' to function return type 'arma::mat' (aka 'Mat<doubld>')
```

Would anyone help me to find a good way to handle this? I'm not sure what type I should use for function return type in this case. If you know another way to convert vector to matrix, then it would be also great :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using [.reshape()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reshape_member) member function (with a dot in front), use the stand-alone version: [reshape()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reshape). There is no need to use the above vec2mat() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You overlooked / ignored details in the Armadillo documentation: `reshape()` is a member function of an *already existing matrix* whereas you try to force it with an assignment.  And the compiler tells you *no mas*.  So listen to the compiler.

#### Working code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat vec2mat(arma::vec x, int nrow, int ncol) {
  arma::mat y(x);
  y.reshape(nrow, ncol);
  return y;
}
```

#### Demo

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("56606499/answer.cpp")  ## filename I used
> vec2mat(sqrt(1:10), 2, 5)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 1.000000 1.732051 2.236068 2.645751 3.000000
[2,] 1.414214 2.000000 2.449490 2.828427 3.162278
>
```

Comment: Thank you, Dirk. I had no experience in this, sorry.

Comment: There is a simpler and more efficient way. Use the stand-alone [reshape()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reshape) function. Example: `mat y = reshape(x, nrow, ncol);`

Comment: I don't see one that takes a vector.

Comment: @hbrerkere Thanks, but as Dirk explained (and in [this documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#reshape)) it does not seem to take a vector.

Comment: A [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors) is still a matrix, just a restricted matrix (one row or one column). The stand-alone reshape() function seems to work fine with any matrix, including vectors.

Comment: @hbrerkere You right there. The `reshape` function works well. Thanks again!